# Subspace of $ P_5$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem:

> Let $U$:= {$p$ ∈ $P_5$$(\mathbb{R})$ : $p(−1)$ = $p(1)$ = $0$}.Show that $U$ is a subspace of $P_5$$(\mathbb{R})$ . Find a basis and determine the dimension of $U$.

Solution:

> 1. Proving that $U$ is a subspace:
>
> Let $n$  be the zero polynomial,  $n$(-1) =$0$= $n$(1) = $0$ then $n$ ∈ $U$.
>
> Let $f$(1)=$0$ and $g$(1)=$0$ ∈ $U$ and $h$= $f$ +$g$ ,then we obtain  that $1$ +$1$=$0$=$h$, so $h$ ∈ $U$
>
> Let further  $c$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ then $f$(1) . $c$= $0$.$c$ = $0$ ∈ $U$, so $P_5$$(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $U$
>
> 2.Basis and Dimension of $U$
>
> $p$=$a_0$+$a_1$$x$+2$a_2$$x^2$+3$a_3$$x^3$+4$a_4$$x^4$ +5$a_5$$x^5$
> Could someone check if my solution of the problem is right and give me a hint how to find the basis of $U$? Is the Basis the answer of the equlation system ?

Comment: I don't get why in part $2$ you are multiplying $x^n$ by $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly the zero polynomial belongs to $U$. 
Now if $f,g \in U$, we have $(f+g)(1)=f(1)+g(1)=0$ and $(f+g)(-1)=f(-1)+g(-1)=0$, hence $f+g \in U$.
Now if $f \in U$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $(cf)(1)=c \cdot f(1)= c \cdot 0=0$ and $(cf)(-1)=c \cdot f(-1)= c \cdot 0=0$, hence $cf \in U$. 
Therefore $U$ is a subspace of $P_5(\mathbb{R})$

For part $2)$ You can write every polynomial in $U$ as $p(x)=(x-1)(x+1)q(x)$ for some $q(x)$ with $\mathrm{deg}\ q(x) \leq 3$. Hence a basis for $U$ is given by $(x-1)(x+1), x(x-1)(x+1), x^2(x-1)(x+1), x^3(x-1)(x+1)$ and $\mathrm{dim}\ U =4$, i.e. if $p(x) \in U$ we have $p(x)=a_0(x-1)(x+1)+a_1x(x-1)(x+1)+a_2x^2(x-1)(x+1)+a_3x^3(x-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)$ where $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ are uniquely determined

Comment: You forgot to multiply the basis elements by $(x-1)(x+1)$..

Comment: Yes sorry, I was giving a basis for the $q(x)$

Comment: @289143 So the Basis is then made of the solution of all four  equalations?

Comment: No, the basis is given by these $4$ polynomials: you can write every $p(x) \in U$ as a linear combination of these polynomials in a uniquely way

Comment: Could you explain also how have you found the polynomials ? Do we have (x-1)(x+1) because p(-1)=p(1) ?

Comment: Exactly, because if $p(\alpha)=0$ I know that $p(x)=(x-\alpha)q(x)$ with $q(x) \neq 0$